# JavaScript faster shift, unshift and splice implementation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have read  this article:

https://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/lets-get-those-javascript-arrays-to-work-fast/

At the end of point 6 the author says:

> Rq about shift/unshift : beware, those are always O(n) operations
>   (meaning : each operation will take a time proportionnal to the number
>   of the array length). Unless you really need to, you shouldn’t use
>   them.  Rather build your own rotating array if you need such feature.

And in the 7th point:

> Rq for shift/unshift users : apply the same principle, with two
>   indexes, to avoid copy/reallocation. One index on the left, one on the
>   right, both starting at the middle of the array. Then you’ll be again
>   in O(1) time. Better. Don’t forget to re-center the indexes when they
>   are ==.

I was wondering what does the author mean when he says `build your own rotating array` and `two indexes,...One index on the left, one on the right, both starting at the middle of the array`. How should be this considerations translated into code (the author doesn't make an example for this use cases)?

Could the principles applied to `shift` and `unshift` be applied to `Array.prototype.splice` too?

**EDIT:** I have an ordered array of `x` coordinates going from indexes `0` (lower values for `x`) to `n` (higher `x` values). I would need to use `myArray.splice(index, 0, item);` several times and insert some new `x` coordinates between the already existent ones if this coordinate is `<` of an higher one and `>` of a lower one (I can easily find that out through a binary search) and I don't want it to reorder the indexes every time I call `splice` cause I have thousands of elements in the array `myArray`.
 Can it be improved using the principles mentioned by the author of the linked article?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Your link leads to the blog. Why not to make a question directly to an author?

Comment: It really depends upon what you want the final result of the array to be and what your operation is.  If you want to remove an item from the array and end up with an actual sequential array with one less item in it, then you won't find better alternatives than `.shift()` or `.splice()` because your objective is to actually modified the array.  If you're just iterating through the array or willing to use some sort of custom data structure, some operations could be improved upon.  But, this is all something that must be optimized to fit the specific operation - not something generic.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh I know, that's because there aren't any anchors on that page so I can't link the specific points.

Comment: @jfriend00 Please check my edit!

Answer (score 1):

All performance questions must be answered by coding a very specific solution and then measuring the performance of that solution compared to your alternative with representative data in the browsers you care about.  There are very few performance questions that can be answered accurately with an abstract question that does not include precise code to be measured.

There are some common sense items like if you're going to put 1000 items in an array, then yes it is probably faster to preallocate the array to the final length and then just fill in the array values rather than call `.push()` 1000 times.  But, if you want to know how much difference there is and whether it's actually relevant in your particular situation, then you will need to code up two comparisons and measure them in multiple browsers in a tool like http://jsperf.com.

The recommendation in that article to create your own `.splice()` function seems suspect to me without measuring.  It seems very possible that a good native code implementation of `.splice()` could be faster than one written entirely in Javascript.  Again, if you really wanted to know, you would have to measure a specific test case.

If you have lots of array manipulations to do and you want to end up with a sorted array, it might be faster to just remove items, add new items onto the end of the array and the call `.sort()` with a custom comparison function when you're doing rather than inserting every new item in sorted order.  But, again which way is faster will depend entirely upon exactly what you are doing, how often you're doing it and what browsers you care about the most.  Measure, measure, measure if you really want to know.

As to whether your specific situation in your edit can be improved with a custom `.splice()`, you'd have to code it up both ways with a representative data set and then test in a tool like perf in multiple browsers to answer the question.  Since you haven't provide code or data to test, none of us can really answer that one for you.  There is no generic answer that works for all possible uses of `.splice()` on all possible data sets in all possible browsers.  The devil is in the details and the details are in all the specifics of your situation.

My guess is that if you're really performance tweaking, you will often find bigger fish to fry in making your overall algorithm smarter (so it has less work to do in the first place) than by trying to rewrite array methods.  The goal is to test/measure enough to understand where your performance bottlenecks really are so you can concentrate on the one area that makes the most difference and not spend a lot of time guessing about what might make things faster.  I'm always going to code a smart use of the existing array methods and only consider a custom coded solution when I've proven to myself that I have a bottleneck in one particular operation that actually matters to the experience of my app.  Per-optimization will just make the code more complicated and less maintainable and will generally be time poorly spent.

Comment: Got it, on the way to test it with `jsperf.com`! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about the same problem and have ended up using B+tree data structure. It takes time and not easy to implement but really good result. It can be considered the combination of both good aspects of array and linked-list:

- In term of search performance, it is similar to binary search on array and even better version ? (not so sure but at least it's tight).
- Modifying (insert, delete) the set without affect all other element index (affect range is very small constant - length of a block)

I would like to hear your thought, you can check this link for the [visualization of b+tree](https://visual-algo.firebaseapp.com/) in action.

Comment: SO is not a discussion forum.

Comment: This is my solution for this question, using B+tree for this case.

Comment: _I would like to hear your thought_ sounds like a start of a discussion.

Comment: I just wanted the author to confirm if this is suitable solution for him.